# Xpath php fetch links

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm using this example to fetch links from a website :

http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php/

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    var_dump($href);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />Link stored: $url";
}
```

It works well; getting all the links; but I cannot get the actual 'title' of the link; for example if i have :

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I want to be able to fetch 'Google' term too.

I'm little lost and quite new to xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$link_title = $href->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the "nodeValue" of the Textnode inside the "a" node. 
You can get that value with

```
$title = $href->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

Full working example:

```
<?php
$dom = DomDocument::loadHTML("<html><body><a href='www.test.de'>DONE</a></body></html>");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $title = $href->firstChild->nodeValue;
    echo "<br />Link stored: $url $title";
}
```

Prints:

> Link stored: www.test.de DONE