# how to insert a child note right before the first element of an XML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<source>        
    <job>
    <title><![CDATA[newsTitle]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[newsTo]]></date>
     .......
```

Now, I need to add

```
<publisher>abc</publisher>
<publisherurl>http://google.com</publisherurl>
```

right after `<source>` tag. I tried the below code but it is adding after the source  tag!

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('C:\test.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/source");
$href = $hrefs->item(0);   
$link = $doc->createElement("publisher","abc");
$href->appendChild($link);
$link = $doc->createElement("publisherurl","www.google.com");
$href->appendChild($link);

print $doc->save('C:\test.xml');
```

How do I add these nodes right after the source?

Comment: Is this PHP? If so, tagging it as such will help.

Comment: Why is the variable that contains a `<source>` node called `href`? [Copy-pasted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291742/) your code, but forgot to rename the variables?

Comment: alternative solution: add nodes with an id or a timestamp, let them add wherever they want and sort for latest addition upon reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$rssDoc = new DOMDocument();
$rss_file = 'C:\test.xml';
$rssDoc->load($rss_file);
$items = $rssDoc->getElementsByTagName('source');

$firstItem = $items->item(0);

$newItem[] = $rssDoc->createElement('lastBuildDate', 'Fri, 10 Dec 2008 22:49:39 GMT');
$newItem[] = $rssDoc->createElement('publisherurl', 'http://www.xyz.com');
$newItem[] = $rssDoc->createElement('publisher', 'XYZ');
foreach ($newItem as $xmlItem){
 $firstItem->insertBefore($xmlItem,$firstItem->firstChild);
} 

echo $rssDoc->save('C:\test.xml');
?>
```

Hey, Manoj Kumar, this should work for you. try this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [DOMNode::insertBefore](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php)

Refer the examples given in the php reference page

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found a solution. Still I have few doubts,

```
$rssDoc = new DOMDocument();
$rss_file = 'C:\test.xml';
$rssDoc->load($rss_file);
$items = $rssDoc->getElementsByTagName('source');

$newItem = $rssDoc->createElement('lastBuildDate', 'Fri, 10 Dec 2008 22:49:39 GMT');
$rssDoc->appendChild($newItem);
$firstItem = $items->item(0);
$firstItem->insertBefore($newItem,$firstItem->firstChild);

$newItem = $rssDoc->createElement('publisherurl', 'http://google.com');
$rssDoc->appendChild($newItem);
$firstItem = $items->item(0);
$firstItem->insertBefore($newItem,$firstItem->firstChild);

$newItem = $rssDoc->createElement('publisher', 'newschannel');
$rssDoc->appendChild($newItem);
$firstItem = $items->item(0);
$firstItem->insertBefore($newItem,$firstItem->firstChild);

echo $rssDoc->saveXML();
```

Is it possible to append these child's one after another in a loop and insert it before similarly ?