# How to fetch last <a> tag value using xpath query

Tags: php, html, xpath

Here is my code :

```
<div class="float-right">
    <span class="lowercase"><a name="pagination" class=" cm-history">«&nbsp;Previous</a></span>
    <span class="strong">1</span>   

<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=2" rel="2" rev="pagination_contents">2</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=3" rel="3" rev="pagination_contents">3</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=4" rel="4" rev="pagination_contents">4</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=5" rel="5" rev="pagination_contents">5</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=6" rel="6" rev="pagination_contents">6</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=7" rel="7" rev="pagination_contents">7</a>                                                         
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=8" rel="8" rev="pagination_contents">8</a>                             
<a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force next-range cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=9" rel="9" rev="pagination_contents">&nbsp;...&nbsp;</a>
<a name="pagination" class=" cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=13" rel="13" rev="pagination_contents">13</a>

<span class="lowercase"><a name="pagination" class="cm-ajax force cm-history" href="vendor.php?dispatch=products.manage&amp;page=2" rel="2" rev="pagination_contents">Next&nbsp;»</a></span>

<span class="pagination-total-items">&nbsp;Total items:&nbsp;</span><span>190&nbsp;/</span>


</div>
```

I want to fetch last `<a>` tag value.

So that output will be : `13`

I have tried following code :

```
$pagination = $xPath->query("//div[@class='float-right'] //a /text()[last()]");
echo $pagination = $pagination->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But it return empty result. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: try this query: ('/<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)/i') - not sure if it will work or not!

Comment: not working @crazymoin

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291742/xpath-php-fetch-links

Comment: please do not edit your question to add the answer to it. It's querstion *and* answer on stackoverflow, answers follow below the question, not inside it. And even instead: please accept the answer that did make it for you. Also next time please search, I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate of that question with a much better answer.

Comment: @hakre this is not a duplicate question which you have marked also that question does have accepted answer. Please reopen it

Comment: Well, it's pretty much a duplicate, what is your argument it's not? It's just about getting a single match by location of a nodelist that is part of a larger xpath expression. And dupes don't need an accepted just at least *one* upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xPath->query("(//a[@name='pagination'])[last()]")
```

Comment: It works with SimpleXmlElement::xpath. Maybe he's using a library that is not capable of processing this particular expression.

Comment: @akond `$pagination->length;` return 1 but `$pagination = $pagination->item(0)->nodeValue;` but it returns empty

Answer (score 0):

I have a cheat for you (note: untested pseudocode):

```
foreach ($xPath->query("//a[@name='pagination']") as $elem) {} // do nothing
echo $elem->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

As for `item(0)->nodeValue` returning an empty string, I think that newlines and other whitespace are considered text nodes as well.

What is the output `item(0)->saveXML()` yield?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fetch last `<a>` tag value.

The `a` element node that contains "13" is not really the last link element in the snippet you have shown. Test this with (the HTML is in "test.html", see [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)):

```
<?php
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "test.html";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//a[@name = 'pagination'][last()]");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Then, the result is

```
Next Â»
```

There is an encoding problem, but it does not matter for your question. More importantly, as you can see, what you are after is actually in the second to last `a` element. Think about a way to uniquely identify this link element, e.g.

```
$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//a[@rel = '13']");
```

which will result in

```
13
```